# How do I bake my own matza?

Tags: passover, matzah, food

I'd really like to bake matza by hand.  I know that it's impractical and inadvisable to try doing it on my own, but I hear that groups of people go to matza factories to do it.  How do I find such a group?  Where do they exist?

Comment: You realize that Jews around world baked their own matzot for millennia. I realize one needs to know what they are doing, but with proper instruction I can't see why it would be a problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

its probably too late for this year, but basically you call up a factory (theres one in lakewood and 5-6 in NYC) and ask when you can come. usually people go in groups, so if you go by yourself theyd probably lump you with another group. or if you have enough people (5 will do) you can go with them and create your own group. warning though that because the bakeries still need to be opererating while your doing your matzot, you wont get to do the whole thing-theyll find you a job to do so that you can be part of it.

Comment: Yudi B, Welcome to mi.yodeya and thanks very much for sharing your advice! Please consider clicking "register," above, to create your account. This will give you access to all of mi.yodeya's features and will allow you to take full credit for your contributions.

Answer (score 2):

If you live in Jerusalem, they sell Shmura Flour at 8 Rapapot St, next to the preschool, and there's usually a bunch of Hassidim making their own matza in a tent across the street.

[image]